# Trig identity for $\tan(\alpha+\beta)$ with $\alpha = \beta = \pi/2$

Tags: trigonometry

The following identity can be found in many [places](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricAdditionFormulas.html):

$$\tan(\alpha \pm \beta) = \frac{\tan \alpha \pm \tan \beta}{1 \mp \tan \alpha \tan \beta}$$

Yet this formula is not correct for $\alpha = \beta = \pi/2$ which gives $0$ for the lhs and is undefined for the rhs.

**My question**
Don't one have to add to the identity that it doesn't hold for this special case?

**Edit**
I am sorry, the first version of my question was incorrect (I wrote $\pi$ instead of $\pi/2$ - perhaps you reconsider your downvote in case you downvoted)

Comment: $\tan \pi = 0$ so $1+ 0\cdot 0 = 1$. So we divide by 1. This isn't undefined.

Comment: It's _implicit_ that the identity holds only when both sides of the equality are well-defined.

Comment: A formula which gives anything for the lhs and is undefined for the rhs is **not** incorrect.

Comment: This case is not special case for the identity, rather when we see $\tan α$ in the formula we ought not to think about $α$ to be anyhow equal to $π/2$, because it is not in the domain of $\tan x$. So there is no question of $α=β=π/2$ being satisfied by the identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed you are correct. The formula has a slightly restricted domain, but people are lazy -- and sometimes it's not even laziness, but just cleanliness: a list of formulas could rapidly become very cluttered if they noted all the exceptions. Instead, when applying a formula on any "not very well behaved" function like $\tan$, I think most authors agree that it's on the reader/user to double-check what's going on at singularities.

Answer (score 0):

For $\alpha = \beta \to \pi/2$ the identity holds to the limit.